# how to know who ping my computer ?

Tags: linux, networking, ping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I know when my computer is pinged?](https://serverfault.com/questions/107163/how-can-i-know-when-my-computer-is-pinged)

I'm using Linux.  I would like to know how to tell who is pinging my computer.  I have seen [this similar question using Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/107163/how-can-i-know-when-my-computer-is-pinged), but I'm not sure it applies to me.

Comment: Same principles apply: Sniff the traffic on the network, or have yor local firewall log ICMP Echo requests your system sees...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It looks like you're asking how to see who's pinging you, right?  One quick and dirty way would be using `tcpdump` to simply monitor all incoming ICMP echo requests:

```
sudo tcpdump -i ethX icmp and icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo
```

where `ethX` is the name of the adapter you're interested in listening to.

Note that tcpdump will resolve hostnames by default, so you might need to add the `-n` option to get IPs instead.

(This is, by the way, basically identical to the instructions given in the question you linked, though they are for Wireshark, a related but separate tool.)

Comment: Apostrophes are missing: `sudo tcpdump -i ethX 'icmp and icmp[icmptype]=icmp-echo'`

Comment: @BenC works also without apostrophes.

Answer (score 19):

You can use tcpdump like this

```
tcpdump ip proto \\icmp
```

and you get this kind of output

> 09:25:22.650727 IP 192.168.1.69 > centos6.lan: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1, l                           ength 40
>   09:25:22.650816 IP centos6.lan > 192.168.1.69: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 1, len                           gth 40

You could use iptables too

```
 iptables -I INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -m state  --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j LOG --log-level=1 --log-prefix "Ping Request "
```

and get messages like this in /var/log/messages (on CentOS at least)

> Nov 14 09:43:35 centos6 kernel: Ping Request IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:d2:2c:38:00:0c:29:fe:8e:bb:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.69 DST=192.168.254.188 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=126 ID=6551 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=1 SEQ=37

Comment: Your short `tcpdump` command show incoming and outgoing (ping and pong). Also nice.